# Which layer is most suitable to handle transaction in Spring 3 Mybatis integrated application?

Tags: spring, spring-3, spring-transactions

Currently I develop Spring 3, Mybatis and Struts2 integrated application using MVC architecture.But I face some difficulties to handle transaction in my application.I use Spring Transaction in my service layer,likes this

Service Layer

```
         @Service("MyService")
         @Transactional
         public class MyServiceImpl implements IMyService {
              @Transactional(readOnly=false)
              public void myMethod() {

              }
         }
```

My question is "Should I use Spring Transaction in my data access layer instead of service layer?" likes this

Data Access Layer

```
        @Repository("MyDAO")
        public class MyDAO implements IMyDAO {
             @Transactional(readOnly=false)
             public void myMethod() {

             } 
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If your calling each DAO method through the Service layer than make the service layer transactional.  If you call some DAO methods independent of the Service layer than the DAO methods will need to be transactional.  You could also make both transactional since Spring will propogate the transactions in both layers, meaning if you call a Service method that is transactional which calls a transactional DAO method, they will share the same transaction.